# Email regex with min length and not max length

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have this regex in JavaScript:

```
new RegExp('^[0-9a-z._-]+@{1}[0-9a-z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-z]{2,}$','i');
```

and I want to modify it.

The last part of the mail must have a minimum value: 2 chars and no maximum length so I can put mails such as .localhost .paris .thisismyexample ...

How may I do that?

Comment: Please provide some strings that you are working with

Comment: Above RegExp does not has any max limit for last part. try /^[0-9a-z._-]+@{1}[0-9a-z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-z]{2,}$/.test('name@domain.mybigname');

Comment: Minimum value of 2 chars - why do u need regex to do that?

Comment: and `{2,}` is 2 or more and you are doing it right I suppose

Answer (score 0):

```
new RegExp('\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,}\b','i');
```